# Scheduled UILocalNotification does not fire after when restarting app or closing app

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

I am scheduling an UILocalNotification with the following code:

```
        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
        notification.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
        notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wurmprophylaxe für Lassy”];
        notification.alertAction = @"Wurmprophylaxe";
        //notification.userInfo = userInfo;
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

The notofication fires until I either terminate the app, restart the app, or re-run through xcode. Simply put, it does not persist. And furthermore it will not fire again, even if the app is running again. It does not matter if the app is in the foreground or not. Once the is terminated, the notification cease to fire and if I list the local notifications, it won't be there anymore. It seems that the UILocalNotification is not being stored. The notification is not delivered, if the app is in foreground, nor background, nor running at all.

Why is it removed between app launches?

Note: If i schedule a new notification, the previous one is removed, too. This is totally weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior. "Terminating" an app by the user will aggressively purge any processes the system is managing for the app. (EDIT: This is true for many background processes, but may not be for local notifications.) Reloading a new app through Xcode definitely will.

The normal process for the app is that it first goes into the background state, then later is terminated by the system while in the background. System-managed tasks will continue and the app will be reawakened if necessary.

Comment: But the notifications should fire again once the system/ios starts again, or? And, previously scheduled notifications shouldn't be removed when a new is scheduled. That can't be normal behaviour!

Comment: If the app is terminated by the user, or replaced by Xcode, the system will purge itself.

Comment: So, it is normal behaviour, that previously scheduled notifications are purged, if the user terminates the app, and the app will have to re-schedule them on launch again, and there will be no notification if the app is not running? Seems a very narrowly defined use case IMHO....?

Comment: However, it CAN'T be intended behaviour, that a previously schedule notification is purged when a new one is scheduled and this is exactly what happens. Either there is something how I schedule the notification or I missing something here?

Comment: Maybe local notifications are handled differently from other system events--right now in a test i threw together I'm getting repeated notifications even after I terminated the app in app switcher.

Comment: This would be the expected behaviour, but that's not happening in my app. :(